# Select random file from directory

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a site where users can submit photos, and then randomly view others photos one by one on another page. I have a directory called "uploads" where the pictures are submitted. I'm having trouble reading the pictures from the file. I just want to randomly select a picture from the directory uploads and have it displayed on the page. Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can use [glob](http://se.php.net/glob) to get all files in a directory, and then take a random element from that array. A function like this would do it for you:

```
function random_pic($dir = 'uploads')
{
    $files = glob($dir . '/*.*');
    $file = array_rand($files);
    return $files[$file];
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I've turned it a little to get more than one random file from a directory using array.

```
<?php

function random_pic($dir)
{
 $files = glob($dir . '/*.jpg');
 $rand_keys = array_rand($files, 3);
 return array($files[$rand_keys[0]], $files[$rand_keys[1]], $files[$rand_keys[2]]);
}

// Calling function

list($file_1,$file_2,$file_3)= random_pic("images"); 

?>
```

You can also use loop to get values.

Comment: +1 better than calling random_pic() three times, as this avoids duplicates.  (Better still to make the 3 an optional parameter to random_pic().)

Answer (score 1):

This single line of code displays one random image from the target directory.

```
<img src="/images/image_<?php $random = rand(1,127); echo $random; ?>.png" />
```

*Target directory:* `/images/`

*Image prefix:* `image_`

*Number of images in directory:* `127`

https://perishablepress.com/drop-dead-easy-random-images-via-php/

---

**Drawbacks**

- images must be named sequentially (eg `image_1.png`, `image_2.png`, `image_3.png`, etc).
- you need to know how many images are in the directory in advance.

---

**Alternatives**

Perhaps there's a simple way to make this work with arbitrary image-names and file-count, so you don't have to rename or count your files.

Untested ideas:

- `<img src=<?php $dir='/images/'; echo $dir . array_rand(glob($dir . '*.jpg')); ?> />`
- `shuffle()`
- `scanDir()` with `rand(1,scanDir.length)`

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use [opendir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) instead of glob() because it's faster

Comment: You are probably correct. You should write an implementation that uses the opendir() method, and post it in your answer.

Comment: Seemingly, you cannot. `opendir()` and `glob()` are said to be two different functions. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119304/select-random-file-using-opendir. And `glob()` would be the one to use here; see https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_glob.asp.

Comment: I obviously meant that it's faster to use the opendir way (opendir, then iterate through the files), not only the opendir function. The link I've included explains what opendir() returns.