# Play a random song with PHP array_rand

Tags: php

I'm trying to have a page select a song at random from a dir of .mp3 files and play it.
This is what I have so far http://pastebin.com/Jypx80RD
 I get this error:

`Second argument has to be between 1 and the number of elements in the array`

For this line:
`$random = array_rand($files, 2);`

Comment: As the error message explains, your second argument of `array_rand` isn't valid, because it isn't within the legal range.  Have you tried fixing this?  If so, what is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select random file using OPENDIR()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119304/select-random-file-using-opendir)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119304/select-random-file-using-opendir/38361953#38361953

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$random = $files[rand(0, count($files) - 1)];
```

Comment: Your method has a chance to produce errors. `rand` has an inlusive upper bound. It should be, `$random = $files[rand(0, (count($files)-1))];` in order to prevent the index from being out of bounds.

Comment: Not a problem. Glad to help.

Comment: @LeeSalminen When I changed it to this, it load the src as `http://domain.com/dir/Array`

Comment: Try var_dump($random) and append the corresponding array key to the end of the variable

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$random = array_rand($files);
```

`$files` looks like it may be empty, from what I had to guess though.