# Get random file from dir

Tags: php, get

i want to get random file from includes folder.

```
<?php
$text = file_get_contents("includes/searchterms.txt");
$text = str_replace("-", " ", $text);
$text=explode('[searchterms]:',$text);
foreach ($text as &$value){
    $value=rtrim($value);
}

$out=array_slice($text,-100);
$out=array_reverse($out);
$out=array_unique($out);

$latest="";
foreach ($out as $value) {
    $latest .= '<a href="';
    $value1 = str_replace(" ", "-", $value);
    $latest .= "/watch/$value1/";
    $latest .= "\">".htmlspecialchars($value)."</a>";
}
echo"$latest";
?>
```

Comment: Ok, so what is wrong with the code you have? Is it giving you errors?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [TAKE THE TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: the code work fine i just want to pick rondom file evry time the page loaded

Comment: can you just show me what to change and ill change it pleas

Comment: Ok I found a DUP if anyone is interested. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478783/select-random-file-from-directory So all you needed to do was do a Google Search

Comment: RiggsFolly if you cant help or dont want to help let others do plz, i did the search on google i dont find what i want thats why i isk here

Comment: I did help, I gave you a link to a perfectly good answer to a very similiar question, here on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

You could use `glob` with a wildcard, to return a array of files inside your given directoy. With `rand`, you could pic a random index, inside this array.

```
$files = glob('includes/*');
$file = $files[rand(0, count($files) - 1)];
$text = file_get_contents($file);
```

Comment: Bit close to down right plagurism there squire

Comment: A Dup Vote would have been more appropriate

Comment: @RiggsFolly What are you complaining about?

Comment: thnq you so much the code work as i want it.

Comment: If you think, the question is a duplicate, mark it it and I vote for it.. I didn't read every single comment, if the question is marked as to broad, and I think, it isn't

Comment: @RiggsFolly the code is working whats wrong with you

Comment: @RiggsFolly i dont get it first you dont wana help and now dont want people to help